# I am creating calculation field which compares the specific category with different cagtegory

Tags: tableau-api

This is the code I am trying to execute

```
IF [Category]= [Parameter ]. [Category] THEN [Sales]
END
```

getting an error :

> " expected THEN to match IF at character 0"

please help.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need `[Parameters.Category]` instead

Comment: I had a typo, now fixed. It is Parameters plural. Its a lot easier to use the insert button and let Tableau spell placeholders like this instead of typing them out by hand. At least that avoids typos getting in the way.